# Specific condition for a map to be isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G=\left ( \mathbb{R}  \space\ \text{where} 0 \notin \mathbb{R},\cdot \right )$ and let r be a positive integer.

Define

$\phi:G\rightarrow G$

$x \mapsto  x^{r}$

Show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism and determine $Ker\left ( \phi \right )$
For which value of r is $\phi$ an isomorphism.

It is easy to show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.
$\left ( \alpha\cdot \beta \right )\phi=\left ( \alpha\cdot \beta \right )^{r}=\alpha^{r}\beta^{r}=\left ( \alpha \right )\phi\cdot \left ( \beta \right )\phi$

Suppose $\alpha$ in G.
$\phi$ is onto because
$\alpha = x^{r} \exists x \in G$.

This implies $x=\alpha^{\frac{1}{4}}$ where $\alpha^{\frac{1}{4}} \in G$.

$Ker\left ( \phi \right )=\left \{ x \in G \mid  \left ( x \right )\phi=e=1 \right \}$

I am unable to show one-to-one or should I say I thought I did until I saw my solution making a comment about \$\phi$ being one-to-one for odd values of r. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of $r$?

Comment: @yoyostein Not given in the question if that is what you are asking. If you are asking the values of r for which I may have found, I haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r$ is odd, then $x^r=1$ implies $x=1$.

Thus the kernel is trivial, thus the map is injective.

Comment: And if r is even, then x^{r}=1 implies x=+1,-1.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So I think it only works for odd values of r.